# Too much Baking Soda in Banana Bread

Tags: bread, baking-soda

I accidentally put in banana bread 1 1/2 tsp of baking soda instead of 3/4 tsp of baking soda.  Is it going to be edible?

Comment: It is in the oven right now.  I did not realize until after the fact.  This is for my son's class and I fear I really screwed this up.   Will it taste bad?

Comment: It also has chocolate chips in it so who knows what that will do to it.   We will see.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Edible, yes. The best banana bread you've ever had? Probably not.

Over-leavened quick breads tend to just get uneven in texture - you may get an uneven loaf with one section that's a little too dense and other sections that are a little too airy, or the whole thing may end up coarse and a little flatter than you'd prefer. But these breads are often rich enough that they're still perfectly tasty.

There's a little risk of the extra baking soda introducing an off flavor, but in practice, I've found that most people won't notice it until you're WAY over-leavened. Taste buds vary but I don't think it'll be an issue for you.

It's been an hour since you've posted the question so I'm assuming that we will have the *actual* answer pretty shortly.

Answer (score 0):

We just made banana bread 1 tsp per three mini loafs. Accidentally used 1 Tablespoon. Oh mg. It has a funny after taste. Bummer. Going to let other people ea it and go back to the drawing board.

Comment: I think this does answer the question, if indirectly - it pretty clearly says too much baking soda will taste bad.